# gsutil file download OSError: Permission denied. KiB

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to download some samples from Google storage to do a sentiment analysis. I am following the instructions but get an error (I actually added a destination file to their instruction and the error is different):

Error as defined by Google on example:
Jorge:python3.7 jbp$ gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/natural-language/sentiment-samples.tgz
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/jbp/Python/env/lib/python3.7/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/**init**.py", line 29, in 
    import tempfile
  File "tempfile.py", line 39, in 
    import functools as _functools
  File "functools.py", line 8
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file functools.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
Jorges-MBP:python3.7 jbarrigapartarrieu$

Error with destination file:
Jorge:python3.7 jbp$ gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/natural-language/sentiment-samples.tgz /User/jbp/Python
Copying gs://cloud-samples-tests/natural-language/sentiment-samples.tgz...
OSError: Permission denied. KiB]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/jbarrigapartarrieu/Python/env/lib/python3.7/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/**init**.py", line 29, in 
    import tempfile
  File "tempfile.py", line 39, in 
    import functools as _functools
  File "functools.py", line 8
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file functools.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 5):

Adding sudo to the line solved my problem

```sh
sudo gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/natural-language/sentiment-samples.tgz ./
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user executing the gsutil command doesn't have permission to write to  `/User/jbp/Python`  or the path doesn't exist.

On a linux system, you can check the path's permissions and owner(s) using `namei`:

```
namei -mo /User/jbp/Python
```

Alternativelly, try saving the file to your working directory:

```
 gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/natural-language/sentiment-samples.tgz ./
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're somehow invoking gsutil with Python 3, which is not supported yet.  The line below the `import tempfile` statement (which is failing) in `gslib/__init__.py` would have raised this error, but it looks like it didn't even get that far:

[https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/9ac524d7f4424ae8c92f001b46f5c1cf2ae68b8d/gslib/**init**.py#L31](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/9ac524d7f4424ae8c92f001b46f5c1cf2ae68b8d/gslib/__init__.py#L31)